# Is it possible for client side javascript to read an arduino board connected via USB to the client?

Tags: javascript, web-services, arduino

Basically what I am attempting to do is to create a JavaScript file served by my WebServer to run on the client that will read a sensor connected to an Adruino board on the client via USB.

That is the client machine has an Arduino connected to it via USB, and then using JavaScript the client machine will read the sensor connected to the Arduino and a Javascript event will trigger based on the value.

I have researched a few different options on connecting an Arduino board to a Web Server, including Johnny 5, Breakout with Node.JS. 
However these are all based on the WebServer being connected to the Arduino board.

I have also looked into PHP and aRest.js but these both require the Arduino board to be connected to a network via WiFi/Ethernet...

Is what I am trying to achieve at all possible or is there no way for JavaScript to access the client machines USB devices?

Comment: There is, you can have a look into something called [WebUsb](https://github.com/webusb/arduino) although it's still in development

Comment: You can do it with a chrome / firefox app. Maybe a plugin also. Javascript not at the moment.